# How to limit size of list and cycle FIFO with new values?

Tags: c#, json

Is there a good way to accomplish this?  I did not find any applicable solutions in searching online.  With the current code implementation below, I can use the top 'n' of the returned values and break out of the loop when count is met.  What I am trying to do instead, is fill the list until length has been reached (user input), and then keep that max length while cycling out the oldest with the newest values taking place of the old as in FIFO order.

```
    private static decimal SMA(int length)
    {
        List<decimal> priceHistory = new List<decimal>();

        var client = new RestClient("https://api.tdameritrade.com/v1/marketdata/" + inputSymbol + "/pricehistory?periodType=month&period=1&frequencyType=daily&frequency=1&needExtendedHoursData=false");
        client.Timeout = -1;
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + ReadAccessToken());
        request.AddParameter("text/plain", "", ParameterType.RequestBody);
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

        dynamic history = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(response.Content);

        int count = 0;

        foreach (var child in history["candles"])
        {
            count += 1;

            while (count <= length)
            {
                var close = (decimal)child["close"];
                priceHistory.Add(close);
                break;
            }
        }

        decimal simpleMovingAverage = priceHistory.Average();
        return simpleMovingAverage; 

    }
```

So for the example data below where length is == 5, once the tenth value is reached at the end of the loop, the sixth value will have recursively cycled all the way into list[0] and the tenth value will be in list[4]:

```
{[
  {
    "open": 177.27,
    "high": 178.84,
    "low": 177.205,
    "close": 178.7,
    "volume": 1081644,
    "datetime": 1613109600000
  },
  {
    "open": 179.0,
    "high": 179.69,
    "low": 176.3242,
    "close": 176.63,
    "volume": 1834033,
    "datetime": 1613455200000
  },
  {
    "open": 176.05,
    "high": 177.3,
    "low": 175.14,
    "close": 176.65,
    "volume": 1578242,
    "datetime": 1613541600000
  },
  {
    "open": 177.25,
    "high": 179.67,
    "low": 176.15,
    "close": 179.37,
    "volume": 2088619,
    "datetime": 1613628000000
  },
  {
    "open": 179.57,
    "high": 180.77,
    "low": 176.2,
    "close": 176.54,
    "volume": 2986839,
    "datetime": 1613714400000
  },
  {
    "open": 176.46,
    "high": 177.09,
    "low": 175.01,
    "close": 176.12,
    "volume": 2271502,
    "datetime": 1613973600000
  },
  {
    "open": 177.54,
    "high": 177.54,
    "low": 174.71,
    "close": 176.17,
    "volume": 2352428,
    "datetime": 1614060000000
  },
  {
    "open": 176.0,
    "high": 177.98,
    "low": 173.76,
    "close": 177.63,
    "volume": 2742552,
    "datetime": 1614146400000
  },
  {
    "open": 177.52,
    "high": 180.75,
    "low": 177.43,
    "close": 178.76,
    "volume": 2634298,
    "datetime": 1614232800000
  },
  {
    "open": 179.44,
    "high": 179.45,
    "low": 174.605,
    "close": 175.06,
    "volume": 3363387,
    "datetime": 1614319200000
  }
]}
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across queuing upon continuing to research.  This actually functions exactly as required.  Posting here in case it could be helpful to others.

```
            Queue priceQueue = new Queue();

            int count = 5;

            foreach (var child in history["candles"])
            {
                var close = (decimal)child["close"];

                priceQueue.Enqueue(close);

                if (priceQueue.Count > count)
                {
                    priceQueue.Dequeue();
                }
            }
```